# How to shorten the length of Tkinter Cobobox in python

Tags: python, user-interface, combobox, tkinter

I want to put small values inside a readonly combobox. But I am getting a long combobox horizontally.

How can i reduce the size.

Comment: can you give your work until now? any image of combobox?

Comment: have you tried setting the `width` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the width option?

```
self.signal_video_framerate_variable = StringVar()
self.signal_video_framerate_combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.signal_standard_label_frame,
                                       textvariable = self.signal_video_framerate_variable,
                                       width = 15)
self.signal_video_framerate_combobox.state(['readonly'])
```

Something to take a look at possibly?
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_dimensions.htm